# how can i know the character set of data stored in Sybase database?

Tags: character, arabic, sap-ase

Good day,

i have a Sybase ASE 12.5 database on windows NT server

i need to know the character set of some Arabic data stored in the database

i checked the database default character set : it is "CP850"

but the stored data are "Arabic" data,so they are stored using another character set

i tried checking the "master..syscharsets" table , i can't find any popular Arabic charsets

Command: select id, csid, name, description from master..syscharsets

[Result: http://dc414.2shared.com/download/CCfkf_RW/syscharsets_cropped.jpg?tsid=20140507-130321-3ade23f2](http://dc414.2shared.com/download/CCfkf_RW/syscharsets_cropped.jpg?tsid=20140507-130321-3ade23f2)

any ideas how to know the character set of the data?

Answer (score 0):

i think it uses cp850 multilingual, try sp_configure "enable unicode conversions" in the server and try also sp_help tableName